# Should I learn first Western Flute or Bansuri?

Tags: flute, lessons, bansuri

I am planning to get lessons on the flute. I do love the bansuri flute, but I am unsure if it's a good idea to start getting lessons on bansuri instead of western flute as almost complete beginner to music theory and playing music.

Would it be ok for me to find a teacher that teaches bansuri or should I look for a teacher that teaches the western flute if my goal in the end is to play bansuri flute?

Comment: Somewhat related [question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/95949/2600).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to play bansuri flute, take lessons on bansuri flute.

Much of what you learn will of course be transferable to western flute if required.

Comment: Seems like a logical move...

Answer (score 0):

Bansuri is a best start. Indian notation is very simple if compared to Western one. The flute sounds just magical (but that's subjective to taste).